# GCC 7 Linker finds nothing despite having libs and lib path defined

Tags: gcc, linker

I' try to compile a simple ANSI c program but cannot link the matter, because any library on the stem the compiler wont find  What could causes the `linker stage` for `GCC` compiler not finding  any library despite having libraries present for GCC 7.

## System definitions

```bash
uname -a
Linux zulu 5.4.0-144-generic #161~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 10 15:55:22 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ldconfig -p | grep gdal
    libgdal.so.20 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20
    libgdal.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgdal.so
 
ldconfig -p | grep libblas
    libblas.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3
    libblas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so

ldconfig -p | grep libgsl
    libgslcblas.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.so.0
    libgslcblas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.so
    libgsl.so.23 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.23
    libgsl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so
```

## Compiler messages

```bash
make tool
gcc  -std=c99 -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -L. -lm -lgsl -lblas -lgdal -o tool-geo-pix  geo-pix.c alg.o
/tmp/ccgCrbdr.o: In function `finalize':
geo-pix.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `GDALClose'
/tmp/ccgCrbdr.o: In function `calcWorldToPixel':
geo-pix.c:(.text+0x24d): undefined reference to `round'
geo-pix.c:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `round'
/tmp/ccgCrbdr.o: In function `main':
geo-pix.c:(.text+0x380): undefined reference to `GDALAllRegister'
geo-pix.c:(.text+0x3b5): undefined reference to `GDALOpen'
geo-pix.c:(.text+0x3f2): undefined reference to `GDALGetGeoTransform'
alg.o: In function `trfm_create':
alg.c:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `gsl_matrix_alloc'
alg.c:(.text+0x185): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_alloc'
alg.c:(.text+0x193): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_alloc'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'tool' failed
make: *** [tool] Error 1
```

## Makefile

```
CC = gcc
LPATH   = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -L.
IPATH   = -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/local/include
CFLAGS  = -std=c99
LIBS    = -lm -lgsl -lblas -lgdal

tool:   geo-pix.c alg.o
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $(IPATH) $(LPATH) $(LIBS) -o tool-geo-pix  geo-pix.c alg.o

alg.o:  alg.c
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $(IPATH) $(LPATH) $(LIBS) -c alg.o
```

Comment: Order of libraries on the command line matter! Libraries are searched in the order found on the command line. If there's no dependency of the library or a function in it yet, then it's discarded and won't be searched again. That's why you should always put libraries *last* on the command line. Or at lease after the object files.

Comment: Regarding your makefile, you don't need to provide the linker flags and libraries when building the object files, only when actually linking. Also, the `tool` rule should be named `tool-geo-pix`, since that's the program your building.

Comment: I also recommend you rely on makefile [*implicit rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) and use the [variables the implicit rules expect](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html). Then `make` will automatically make sure the commands run have the arguments in the correct order.

Comment: So at least the correction works:
`$(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $(IPATH) $(LPATH) -o tool  geo-pix.c alg.o $(LIBS)`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comments, this is how the makefile could be rewritten:

```
# Flags and options for the preprocessor and the compiler
# for the generation of object files
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include/gdal
CFLAGS   = -Wall -Wextra -std=c99

# Flags and options for the linker and the generation of the
# executable program file
LDFLAGS  = 
LDLIBS   = -lm -lgsl -lblas -lgdal

# Build the executable program from these two object files
tool-geo-pix: geo-pix.o alg.o
```

Implicit rules will build the object files from their source files, and the executable program from the listed object files.